# Age structure of German population; 1925 census, large cities

Tags: data-request, population, germany

Anybody knows where I can find data about German census at the city level for the period 1925-1935?

In particular, I am interested in the age structure of the population of the largest cities, the so-called **Großstädte** (> 100 000 inhabitants).

**EDIT:** I found out that in that period there have been two censuses in Germany, one in 1925 and one in 1933. I found data for year 1933 but I am still striving to find data about 1925 census. Any help in this direction?

Comment: Try to contact the author of this image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Germany_sex_by_age_1933_06_16.png

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed I managed how to find population structure in 1933 but I am still trying to get data for 1925 census.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out the information provided by the German Federal Statistical Office https://histat.gesis.org/histat/de/index where one can find a large variety of time series data for social, economic and historical research. Both registration and download of the data are free. Another starting point for the search could be http://www.historische-statistik.de/datensaetze-karten-volkszaehlungsstatistiken/ which is a compendium of different historical data sets and data sources. The data is collected through different lectures at the University Bonn.

Comment: Done, hope this is more helpful now.